# Does Call by Name or Call by Value have an effect in Big O Notation?

Tags: scala

Would the way the code is evaluated either though call by value or call by name have an effect in Big O Notation? Why or why not?

Comment: Yes, if the call-by-name is causing parts of the code to be evaluated less often or more often than with call-by-value.

Comment: Big O Notation of *what*? Big O is simply a way of characterizing the growth rate of a mathematical function. It doesn't make sense to ask about the growth rate of a function if you don't say what the function is.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because a by-name argument is evaluated every time it is accessed.

For example, take a method that is `O(n)` because it evaluates its argument `n` times, and a value that involves a computation that is also `O(n)`.

If the argument is passed by value then this is `O(n)` because the argument is evaluated `1` time and accessed `n` times.

If the argument is passed by name then this is `O(n^2)` because the argument is evaluated `n` times and each evaluation is `O(n)`.